# In Alamofire only the UINavigationController is called! no other response

Tags: ios, swift2, alamofire, swifty-json

I am using [this tutorial](http://ashishkakkad.com/2015/02/google-place-autocomplete-view-with-swift-language-through-alamofire-networking-library/) to auto-complete the google places.

I have installed the alamofire and swiftyJSON through cocoapads.

My issue is When I enter text in searchbar, nothing happens.

On my ViewControlller:

```
    let gpaViewController = GooglePlacesAutocomplete(
    apiKey: "MY-API-KEY",
    placeType: .Address
    )

    gpaViewController.placeDelegate = self

    presentViewController(gpaViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

On my GooglePlacesAutoComplete View Controller:

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON

enum PlaceType: CustomStringConvertible {
case All
case Geocode
case Address
case Establishment
case Regions
case Cities

var description : String {
    switch self {
    case .All: return ""
    case .Geocode: return "geocode"
    case .Address: return "address"
    case .Establishment: return "establishment"
    case .Regions: return "regions"
    case .Cities: return "cities"
    }
}
}

struct Place {
    let id: String
    let description: String
}

protocol GooglePlacesAutocompleteDelegate {
    func placeSelected(place: Place)
    func placeViewClosed()
}
```

**Only this set of codes is called:**

```
class GooglePlacesAutocomplete: UINavigationController {

var gpaViewController: GooglePlacesAutocompleteContainer?

var placeDelegate: GooglePlacesAutocompleteDelegate? {
    get { return gpaViewController?.delegate }
    set { gpaViewController?.delegate = newValue }
}

convenience init(apiKey: String, placeType: PlaceType = .All) {
    let gpaViewController = GooglePlacesAutocompleteContainer(
        apiKey: apiKey,
        placeType: placeType
    )

    self.init(rootViewController: gpaViewController)
    self.gpaViewController = gpaViewController

    let closeButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.Stop, target: self, action: "close")

    gpaViewController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = closeButton
    gpaViewController.navigationItem.title = "Enter Address"
}

func close() {
    placeDelegate?.placeViewClosed()
}

}
```

**No indication of this:**

```
class GooglePlaceSearchDisplayController: UISearchDisplayController {
override func setActive(visible: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    if active == visible { return }

    searchContentsController.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = true
    super.setActive(visible, animated: animated)

    searchContentsController.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = false

    if visible {
        searchBar.becomeFirstResponder()
    } else {
        searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
    }
}
}
// MARK: - GooglePlacesAutocompleteContainer
class GooglePlacesAutocompleteContainer: UIViewController {
    var delegate: GooglePlacesAutocompleteDelegate?
    var apiKey: String?
    var places = [Place]()
    var placeType: PlaceType = .All

convenience init(apiKey: String, placeType: PlaceType = .All) {
    self.init(nibName: "GooglePlacesAutocomplete", bundle: nil)
    self.apiKey = apiKey
    self.placeType = placeType
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let tv: UITableView? = searchDisplayController?.searchResultsTableView
    tv?.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")

}

}
```

**Or this:**

```
// MARK: - GooglePlacesAutocompleteContainer (UITableViewDataSource / UITableViewDelegate)
extension GooglePlacesAutocompleteContainer: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return places.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = self.searchDisplayController?.searchResultsTableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell?

    // Get the corresponding candy from our candies array
    let place = self.places[indexPath.row]

    // Configure the cell
    cell!.textLabel!.text = place.description
    cell!.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.DisclosureIndicator

    return cell!
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    delegate?.placeSelected(self.places[indexPath.row])
}
}

// MARK: - GooglePlacesAutocompleteContainer (UISearchDisplayDelegate)
 extension GooglePlacesAutocompleteContainer: UISearchDisplayDelegate {
    func searchDisplayController(controller: UISearchDisplayController, shouldReloadTableForSearchString searchString: String!) -> Bool {
    getPlaces(searchString)
    return false
}

private func getPlaces(searchString: String) {
    let url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json"
    Alamofire.request(.GET, url).responseJSON { response in
        switch response.result {
        case .Success(let data):
            let json = JSON(data)
            let name = json["name"].stringValue
            print(name)
        case .Failure(let error):
            print("Request failed with error: \(error)")
        }
    }
}
}
```

Apologies for long code. Am not sure, where I made a mistake. 
I also set the delegate for `searchBar` in xib
I double checked the installation of Cocoapads, Alamofire and SwiftyJson. Can someone please help me? I'm new to these things..

Comment: did u set your UISearchDisplayController delegate = self?

Comment: yes, I set the delegate to self. but its not working.

Answer (score 0):

**You Have To Make Object Of UISearchBar Like This...**

```
lazy var searchBar : UISearchBar = UISearchBar()
```

**In Did Load**

```
searchBar.delegate = self
```